# Count resulted records using linq to sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, count

i use linq to sql query for retrive records from database.
i use a query,for binding a gridview.

```
   protected void grdBind()
        {
            try
            {
                EventManagerDataContext db = new EventManagerDataContext();


                var z = (from x in db.EMR_EVENTs
                         join y in db.EMR_CLIENTs on x.ClientID equals y.ClientID
                         where y.ClientID==x.EventID
                         select x.EventID).Count();



                var q = from a in db.EMR_CLIENTs
                        join b in db.EMR_EVENTs on a.ClientID equals b.ClientID     
                        join c in db.EMR_ACCOUNTs on a.ClientID equals c.ClientID
                        join d in db.EMR_SUBSCRIPTIONs on c.Account_ID equals d.Account_ID
                        join f in db.EMR_SUBSCRIPTION_KINDs on d.Subscription_kind_ID equals f.Subscription_kind_ID


                        select new
                        {
                            Customer = a.Name,
                            Events = z,
                            TurnOver = f.Monthly_Fee,
                            StartDate = d.Start_Date,
                            EndDate = d.End_Date,
                            CreteDate = d.Create_Date,
                            ClientID = a.ClientID,
                            EventID = b.EventID,
                            SubscriptionID = d.Subscription_ID,
                            Subscription_kind_ID=f.Subscription_kind_ID,
                            Account_ID=c.Account_ID,
                        };



                 grid.DataSource = q.ToList();
                 grid.PageSize = int.Parse(drpPageSize.SelectedValue);
                 grid.DataBind();


            }
            catch
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

and i recieve this output for that,

[image]

i recieve this output for this query but i don't want this output ,
i want like this output.

**clientname**         **events**

ketan                  18

monika                 12

and others records so on means i recieve here client name 9 times and he created events but i want some of events and client name only one time

means i want only one name of client and total number of events,i am new to linq to sql.
so what is the changes in code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found solution .[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927194/linq-to-sql-join-count?rq=1)

ans also use with this.[useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767143/linq-join-with-count)

here is my solution.

```
 EventManagerDataContext db = new EventManagerDataContext();



                var q = from a in db.EMR_CLIENTs
                        join b in db.EMR_EVENTs on a.ClientID equals b.ClientID into z                       
                        join c in db.EMR_ACCOUNTs on a.ClientID equals c.ClientID
                        join d in db.EMR_SUBSCRIPTIONs on c.Account_ID equals d.Account_ID
                        join f in db.EMR_SUBSCRIPTION_KINDs on d.Subscription_kind_ID equals f.Subscription_kind_ID


                        select new
                        {
                            Customer = a.Name,
                            Events =z.Where(b =>b.ClientID==a.ClientID).Count(),                         
                            TurnOver = f.Monthly_Fee,
                            StartDate = d.Start_Date,
                            EndDate = d.End_Date,
                            CreteDate = d.Create_Date,
                            ClientID = a.ClientID,
                            SubscriptionID = d.Subscription_ID,
                            Subscription_kind_ID=f.Subscription_kind_ID,
                            Account_ID=c.Account_ID,
                        };



                 grid.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are using join syntax in query you do not need to use 'where'
then change your query to :

```
 var z = (from x in db.EMR_EVENTs
                     join y in db.EMR_CLIENTs on x.ClientID equals y.ClientID
                     select x.EventID).Count();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..@kamran but it not works...i try with this one.

Comment: i got total number of events like ketan 30 monika 30 ,and so on

Comment: i want like that if ketan create 18 events then shows ketan 18,and monika create 12 events then shows monika 12....not sum of it..