# Get count of two joined data tables

Tags: c#, datatable, count, inner-join

I have two data tables in my C# code, each with a single column called ID of type `string`.

I want to (inner) join the two tables on the ID column and get a count of the common rows. I don't need the IDs themselves, just the count of common IDs.

One of the tables may have duplicate IDs but the join must consider only distinct values so if there are two rows with ID=544 they should only count as one.

The two tables may have over a million rows each so performance is an issue.  What would be the simplest and most efficient way to code this in C#?

Comment: show the code what you have tried so far

Comment: Please before you ask google your tags  & numerous clear concise statements of your actual question, keeping one as a title. Eg you can combine two hits from 'c# datatable count number of values in a common column'. PS How is your data stored *exactly*? And please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq join with COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767143/linq-join-with-count)

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ - I haven't tried anything because I know of no data table methods to join and I couldn't find anything on Google with Linq that I could use.  I would hate to dump the data into SQL and run a SQL query which I do know :-).  Or I could sort the tables and traverse in tandem in one iteration (merge join style) but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @philipxy - I saw that, but I didn't understand which part was the left join that I need removed and which part I need to keep to get a count.  In addition, I think there you get a count for each row in one of the tables.

Comment: Do you _need_ to store both sets in data tables?  There's a huge overhead to that.  If you store them (preferably sorted) in arrays or lists there are much faster and more concise ways to do this. And plenty of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: You do not *need* a join. What you want can be described in terms of a join and other things. You could describe it *without* join. You could iterate through arrays. But you have not answered the comment questions you were asked so how can we know? [mcve]

Comment: 1. What about your question here makes you think you are going to get different answers than those google hits? *Ask your question clearly with your requirements.* 2. Why do you mention left join? It doesn't do what you want. 3. If you want unique/distinct values *add that to your googling*. But the duplicate *is* for unique rows. 4. The hits tell you how to join and how to count. If you want the count for the join then join then count. If you don't want SQL add -SQL. PS Since you have those answers, try them, then when you are stuck give code & ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs a simple inner join. If i understood you properly here i have given the solution. Try it and let me know if it solves your problem

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace JoinDatatablesConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
            for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
            {
                DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
                dr1["ID"] = i + "A";
                dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
                DataRow dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
                dr2["ID"] = i + "A";
                dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);
            }
            DataRow dr3 = dt2.NewRow();
            dr3["ID"] = "7A";
            dt2.Rows.Add(dr3);

            var commonData = (from f1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                               join f2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                               on f1.Field<string>("ID")
                               equals f2.Field<string>("ID")
                               select f1.Field<string>("ID"))
                                           .Distinct().ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("Common Data : ");
            foreach(var item in commonData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Common Data Count : " + commonData.Count);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to select distinct. And have duplicates in your test data. And tell the OP the need a [mcve].

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ - Works!  Thanks!

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ - Oh wait, how do I code select distinct?  I am a Linq newbie.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Comment: @user3517113 You need to put more effort in--which seems to be the tiniest bit of effort. Being a newbie does not excuse you from not wasting others' time.